# HERE maps - Move a marker from one position to another

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am using HERE maps api v3/3.1 for my map. I am able to add a marker but I dont know how to move the marker to another position/update the marker position. Can someone please give me a example how I can do that in v3/3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three steps to follow.

**Step 1**

First you need to keep a reference of the marker, so that you can update its properties later

```js
// Step 1: Instantiate car marker with its initial position
var carMarker = new H.map.DomMarker({ lat: 48.8567, lng: 2.3508 });
```

**Step 2**

We add the marker to the map.

```js
// Step 2: Add marker to the map
map.addObject(carMarker);
```

**Step 3**

Finally we move the marker using *setGeometry* on the marker reference. In this case, we are moving the marker after a timer of 5 seconds, but that could be whichever event you need (input event, XHR response, etc ...)

```js
// Step 3: Move marker
setTimeout(function() {
  carMarker.setGeometry({ lat: 48.8567, lng: 12.3508 })
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setGeometry()` is the method you need. It accepts `geo.Point` or `geo.MultiPoint`.

For more information see [Marker#setGeometry apireference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics_api/h-map-marker.html#h-map-marker__setgeometry)

```
// update marker's position using single point:
marker.setGeometry({lat: 53, lng: 13.5});

// or update using MultiPoint
// marker.setGeometry(new H.geo.MultiPoint([{lat: 53, lng: 13}, {lat: 52, lng: 10}]));
```